# Installing Ruby on Rails on a Mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, macos, installation, homebrew

How do I install Ruby on Rails on my Mac OSX?

So far I've managed to install Xcode and Homebrew, but I haven't found Command Line Tools for Xcode because Apple's Developer Site is down.

Answer (score 4):

In the menu bar in Xcode, go to

Preferences > Downloads > Install Command Line Tools